# ElectronJS app icon not appearing in Apple App Store Connect

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, app-store-connect, electron-forge

I am writing an electronJS application for MacOS. My build works fine and I can run the application perfectly after running `electron-forge make` command. The icon also appears in the file.

Then I followed this document to sign my application: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide using electron-forge.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Name of your app.
APP="YourApp"
# The path of your app to sign.
APP_PATH="/path/to/YourApp.app"
# The path to the location you want to put the signed package.
RESULT_PATH="~/Desktop/$APP.pkg"
# The name of certificates you requested.
APP_KEY="3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Company Name (APPIDENTITY)"
INSTALLER_KEY="3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Company Name (APPIDENTITY)"
# The path of your plist files.
CHILD_PLIST="/path/to/child.plist"
PARENT_PLIST="/path/to/parent.plist"
LOGINHELPER_PLIST="/path/to/loginhelper.plist"

FRAMEWORKS_PATH="$APP_PATH/Contents/Frameworks"

codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libffmpeg.dylib"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libnode.dylib"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/$APP Helper"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper.app/"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$LOGINHELPER_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/Contents/Library/LoginItems/$APP Login Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/$APP Login Helper"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$LOGINHELPER_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/Contents/Library/LoginItems/$APP Login Helper.app/"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$CHILD_PLIST" "$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/$APP"
codesign -s "$APP_KEY" -f --entitlements "$PARENT_PLIST" "$APP_PATH"

productbuild --component "$APP_PATH" /Applications --sign "$INSTALLER_KEY" "$RESULT_PATH"
```

It signed successfully and generated `myapp.pkg` file.

Then I tried submitting this `myapp.pkg` to Apple App Store Connect using Transporter https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784

It can submit the app successfully but my app icon (which appears correctly in my desktop) doesn't appear here or in the App Store Connect, instead shows the default icon for it.

I am using the .icns file for it. Any thoughts on how to get my icon to appear would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And if you add this file into your electron-forge project, *entitlements.mac.plist* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key><true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key><true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key><true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key><true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key><true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key><true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

and my *electron-builder* config for integrate this file :

```
pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
        removeElectronJunk: true,
        externals: ['typeorm', 'better-sqlite3'],
        nodeIntegration: true,
        mainProcessFile: 'src/main.js',
        rendererProcessFile: 'src/renderer.js',
        builderOptions: {
            appId: "electron-app",
            mac: {
                icon: "./build/app-icon.icns",
                entitlements: "./build/entitlements.mac.plist",
                entitlementsInherit: "./build/entitlements.mac.plist",
                darkModeSupport: true
            },
```